Setting DataGrid SelectedItem does not select item in grid
I have an Avalonia DataGrid. ItemSource and SelectedItem are binded in axaml.
After i refresh collection DataGrid loses focus and SelectedItem becomes null.
I want to get selected item back on DataGrid.
I tried set SelectedItem in DataGrid_SelectionChanged event, but it doesn't work as expected.

Found solution :
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object? sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var indexItem = ViewList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == e.RemovedItems[0].Id);
    if(indexItem != null)
    {
        DataGrid.SelectedIndex = ViewList.IndexOf(indexItem);
    }
}

